# Convert Java object into JSON array for Retrofit call

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

I need to send an array of Strings using a Retrofit call. To do that I decided to create an object like this one:

```
public class SendEmailsList {

    ArrayList<String> emails;

    public SendEmailsList(ArrayList<String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }
}
```

And my JSON String must be like this:

```
{
  "emails": ["email@server.com","email1@server.com","email2@server.com"]
}
```

This is the `POST` method defined in my interface:

```
@POST("/v2/companies/{companyId}/invite")
  Call<ArrayList<String>> inviteMembers(@Path("companyId") String companyId, @Body SendEmailsList emails);
```

And this is the method that makes the Retrofit call:

```
public void SendNetworkRequest() {

    OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    okhttpBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request request = chain.request();

            Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
        }
    });

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.ENDPOINT)
            .client(okhttpBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    CompanyService invite = retrofit.create(CompanyService.class);

        Call<ArrayList<String>> call = invite.inviteMembers("5602eb7ce49c9cd70409f206", new SendEmailsList(invitedEmails));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Response<ArrayList<String>> response) {

                System.out.println("Internal Users: " + response.code());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e("Internal Users Activity", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
12-21 14:36:49.953 27953-27953/com.construct.test E/Internal Users Activity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How can I figure out what is going on?

Comment: try to get Call<SendEmailList> inplace of Call<Arraylist<String>>..... because you expect an array of strings but your json response is an object inside which list of strings in kept.

Comment: enjoy happy coding